# Grant a Service Account Access to all Analytics accounts

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

I have hundreds of individual analytics accounts right now which I would like to have API access to. Normally, you can just go to the admin page of an account and give access to the service account by entering the service account email. The problem I am having is that I have hundreds of accounts. I'd really not like to add my service email to each account manually. Is there a way I can have access to each analytics account through API without manually entering my email under each account?

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't helpful...but if you have someone that can work with python/selenium or Winautomation, this would be a straightforward task.

Comment: oh you're right! I can totally build a crawler to do this for me. Simple task. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

The only way is through a google account that already has access to all the analytics accounts that interest you.